# Largest Number ( javascript ) explanation

Tags: javascript

I was working on leetcode question and come across this question and saw an answer online.

According the MDN, we should an inner function sort(function(a,b) return a + b) to sort an array properly.

Can someone explain how does the closure works and further explain the following codes?
(I don't quite understanding the sequence of how the comparison is done)

```
/*Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.

For example, given [3, 30, 34, 5, 9], the largest formed number is 9534330.

Note: The result may be very large, so you need to return a string instead of an integer.*/
var largestNumber = function(nums) {
        return nums.sort(function (a,b){
            return (b + '' + a) - (a + '' + b);
        }).join('').replace(/^0*/,'') || '0';
};
var nums= [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
console.log(largestNumber(nums));
```

Comment: There is no closure here?

Comment: Where did you saw this answer? Please link it, and attribute the author of the code.

Comment: Did you mean `function (a, b) { return a - b; }`?

Comment: @Bergi Anonymous functions are sometimes (read: in PHP) called "closures".

Comment: A simple lexicographic (string) comparison would have suited quite as well: `nums.sort().reverse()`

Comment: @Siguza: Urgh. Functions (created by function expressions or not) are sometimes called closures in JS as well, but only if they close over something…

Comment: @Bergi i don't think this code `nums.sort().reverse()` would work, it would sort the items in the array numerically, the string cast is necessary to have them sorted as strings.

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia: No, `.sort()` without a comparison function does not sort numerically, but always lexicographical - it does cast them to strings implicitly. Try it!

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia: Ah, but it doesn't work indeed, because `'3' < '30'`

Comment: @Bergi yes, but good to know about the `.sort()` cast thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What this sort is basically doing is for each element in the array `a` and `b`. Check which way the numbers would be high based on how they would be ordered. For example, if `a = 30` and `b = 5`. Then:

```
(b + '' + a) - (a + '' + b) 
530 - 305
225
```

Since this is a positive number it means `b` would be the left of of `a` in the final array (*string*).

So notice that in the example data `[3, 30, 34, 5, 9]`, the element `9` compared to any other element would result in `9` being on the left (meaning it's the lowest item in the array). Here is a snippet example of each comparison done with some extra console information (*to show how each comparison is being done and the result, notice that `9` was always lower compared to each element. Then the next number `5` is lower than everything but `9`*):

```js
var largestNumber = function(nums) {
        return nums.sort(function (a,b){
            var priority = (b + '' + a) - (a + '' + b)
            console.log((b + '' + a) + " - " + (a + '' + b) + " => " + (priority));
            if(priority > 0) console.log(a + " > " + b);
            else console.log(a + " < " + b);
            return (b + '' + a) - (a + '' + b);
        }).join('').replace(/^0*/,'') || '0';
};
var nums= [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
console.log(largestNumber(nums));
```

Answer (score 0):

The snipped you presented is basically a code that builds the largest possible "number" out of the elements of an array.

**Lets imagine we have the following input: [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]**

First of all, the sort is taking a function as parameter. Its job is to sort the nums in descending lexicographic order (so a 34 would be lesser than a 5, because 3 is lesser than 5). It does that by comparing the values of the strings composed by the "ab" and "ba", so if "ba" - "ab" is a negative value, it will assume that 'a' is lesser than 'b', and so on.

**At this step you have: [9,5,34,3,30]**

After the sorting takes place, it invokes the join() function with '' as parameter, which means it will join the elements into a string, separating each element with the given paramenter, which is no separation at all.

**At this step you have: "9534330"**

Then, you have a call to the replace function, which will look for a certain pattern and replace it by the given second parameter. The first parameter in this case is a regular expression, which will match each string with '0' at the beginning of it and that contain zero or more occurences of '0'.

(Reference to Regular expressions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)

**At this step you still have: "9534330"**

Finally, at the end of the return expression there is an || '0', which basically means that it will return '0' in case the first part of the return expression is false, either by wrong or missing input.